# I want to make different views for mobiles on rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mobile, rubygems

I installed `rack-user_agent gem` and edited `application_controller` like below but doesn't work. Mine is rails4.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :detect_mobile 

  private 
     def detect_mobile
        case request.user_agent
        when /mobile/i
            request.variant = :mobile
        end
     end 
 end
```

app > views > pages > home.html.erb & mobile.html.erb

Does anyone know how to fix this? or someone knows better ways to suggest on this?

Comment: you can make mobile views by css only by @media query http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I know but I want to make other view files to make them appear.

Answer (score 0):

If the content all almost same foe web and mobile view then you have to use same html code just use css @media screen

[w3schools css](http://w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

If you want a particular file render under mobile view only then you can use rack-user_agent gem

just create an helper in application_helper.rb

```
def is_mobile?
   request.from_smartphone?
end
```

and put use this helper in views where you need to render file only on mobile like:

```
<%= 
if is_mobile?
    render "mobile_file"
end
%>
```

If you have two different views for mobile and web and you want controller will return views based on the variant
then you can use like

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  def your_method
    #your code
    if view_context.is_mobile?
      render "mobile_view"
    else
     render "web_view"
   end

  end
end
```

Comment: already checked. However what i want to do for this time is make another view files and make them appear on mobile screen.

Comment: Do I have to put codes like this to any file I want to make it appear on mobile screen? or only application controller then its fine.

Comment: No you have to add on all the files as you have to render diffrent views for each action and each action have its own view not a common view I have added both the ways where you can use in controllers and views

Answer (score 0):

Try this Gem ......

```
gem 'mobile-fu'
```

https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu

Hope this will work for you.